# Account sharing Rule

Tags: profile, sharing-rule, owd

My requirement is "Log in as any user with a profile other than System Administrator. Ensure the user has access to view all Account record types but is only able to create and edit those with the College/University and Competitor/Source Record Type. All records with "United Health Group Company" as the record type should be read-only. "

I've 3 record types for account object as mentioned above. I've set security access of Account object as CRE and OWD set as "Public Read only". Also I've created a sharing rule in order to all "All Internal Users" have Read/Write access to each others records.

Sharing Rule : Account: Account Record TypeEQUALSCompetitor/Source,College/University

But user's are getting edit access on the record type "United Health Group Company"  that we don't want, we want only for 2 record types Read and Edit access to all internal users.

BR,
Abhishek

Comment: Make sure the users' profiles don't have Modify All Data system permission or modify all for Account object.

Comment: Hi Thomas, user's profile are having read,create,edit,view all permission for account object. Even then it's not working.

Comment: I would take away View All for a profile where you want to restrict the users with Sharing, but agree that it shouldn't make a difference if OWD is Public Read Only. They don't have the read-only RT assigned to the profile, right? And the records they can edit but shouldn't are created by other users, who are not below them in role hierarchy?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Record types are assigned to the profile we can't control the Read only or Edit access for record type on the profile I guess.